# How can i fix the syntax?

Tags: python

I don't know how to fix the syntax

```
import os, sys, subprocess

subprocess.call("grep -o 'tag[^"]*' test > update", shell=True)
```

```
    subprocess.call("grep -o 'tag[^"]*' test > update", shell=True)
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried using `os.system` as well but i get the same error

Comment: You need to escape the `"` character in the regex

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python strings are delimited by quotes, in your case the double quote that starts `"grep -o ...`. But there's also a double quote inside `'tag[^"]*`:

```
subprocess.call("grep -o 'tag[^"]*' test > update", shell=True)
#                             ~^~
```

So Python sees this as

```
                "grep -o 'tag[^"
subprocess.call(                ]*' test > update", shell=True)
```

Which is invalid syntax. You need to escape the double quotes by putting `\` before it:

```
subprocess.call("grep -o 'tag[^\"]*' test > update", shell=True)
#                              ^ Added this
```

or use a different pair of quotes, like triple `'`:

```
subprocess.call('''grep -o 'tag[^\"]*' test > update''', shell=True)
#               ^^^              changed these      ^^^
```